# How to show index of page with htaccess?

Tags: html, .htaccess

I'm new to hosting and I'm trying to get a basic "index of" page to show.

I have an address ie: www.mydomain.com/files

I just have some zip files in that location that I'd like to show and allow users to download but not sure how to do this.  At the moment I just get a FORBIDDEN page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `.htaccess` file and put

```
Options +Indexes
```

In it.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```